# Macro with << operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

I'm using `BOOST_LOG_SEV` macro to log information in my application. But now I need to capture logging information also in my spacial way. I decided to create new `BOOST_LOG_SEV_ABC` macro that redirects information to `BOOST_LOG_SEV` and my function `aaa`.

```
#define BOOST_LOG_SEV_ABC(logger, lvl)   BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, lvl)


void aaa(std::strstream value)
{
    std::cout<<"this is my str "<<value;
}
```

Unfortunatly I have no idea how to pass stream to aaa in macro. How to write macro `BOOST_LOG_SEV_ABC` to make all this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost log macros return an object that use the operator<< to stream data to the logging sinks.  Instead of capturing this data at the front end, you could setup a custom sink to accept the messages logged via the standard boost logging macros.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sinks.html

The other option would be to implement your own object that uses the operator<< (a stream of some sort) and the sends the data on to boost log and to your aaa function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't<sup>1</sup>, that function is hardcoded to use `std::cout`.  That's why formatted output functions usually take two arguments: the stream to use for output and the value to format.

<sup>1</sup> You could play tricks with temporarily replacing the `cout` buffer object, but that would be mutating global state to solve a local problem, which is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: "function is hardcoded" -- it's not explicitly out of scope to change `aaa()`'s implementation/signature.